# Setup > Login Access Policies in Full Copy Sandbox doesn't have radio options available to allow Users to grant login access for Managed Packages

Tags: managed-package, sandbox, appexchange, user, grant-login-access

In our Production Org, when I go to Setup > Login Access Policies, I am able to select which Support Organizations that I want my users to be able to grant login access to, so that they can get assistance on their own without needing an admin to grant login access for the support org:

[image: Production Org]

When I try to do the same thing in our Full Copy UAT Sandbox, they all show as Not Available:

[image: UAT Org]

> **On mouseover of the Info box, it says:**
>
> All of the packages from this
> company are licensed for your entire organization. Only administrators
> can grant access.

---

> **Question:** This would appear to be because these apps have full user
> access in Sandbox, even though in Production they are restricted to a
> certain number of assigned User Licenses. How (if at all) can I change
> these apps in Sandbox so that they are licensed in the same way as
> they are in production, or at the very least allow my users to grant
> login access to support teams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sandboxes are always granted perpetual site-wide licenses. Therefore, only administrators can grant access to the support team for a sandbox. Your only real option would be to change users that need to grant login access in sandboxes to administrators in those sandboxes.

Comment: Yikes - not a good option at all :( I was afraid of that, but wanted to be sure. Thank you